# Разные стили в разных view (вьюхах)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, mvc, view, frontend

Добрый день, изучаю Rails, решил сделать лэндинг.

Главная страница лэндинга состоит из блоков, у блока есть элементы, например, текстовый (заголовок\призыв к действию\описание спец. предложения\другой текст) и фон.

Дано: модель Block, у которой есть поле background, в которое загружается фоновое изображение и поле text, в которое загружается текст блока.
Пример:

```
# Код в контроллере
@index_blocks = Block.where(page: 'index')

#Код во view-файле
<% @index_blocks.each do |block| =>
<div style="background: <% block.background %>" >
<p><%= block.text %></p>
</div>
```

Или же можно просто вставлять текст прямо между тегами в верстке, а фон выставлять прямо в CSS статично каждому элементу отдельно, вопрос не об этом. Как можно размещать в каждый элемент во вьюхе разный фон?
Первое, что приходит в голову - это использовать аттрибут 'style' у элемента, как показано в примере. Но я сомневаюсь, что это правильное решение. Как обычно это делается? Может можно прикрепить к каждому view-файлу отдельный файл стилей? Или обычно используется какой-то фронтенд-фреймоворк?

Comment: А в чем проблема атрибута `style`? Используйте его вместе с `css` базой `div` блока. Что касается фронта, то можете посмотреть в сторону Vue.js.

Comment: Надо оценивать решение не по абстрактной "правильности", оцениваемой третьими лицами, а самостоятельно прикидывая последствия внедрения решения. Какие последствия у этого? Кастомизировать можно только фон: вам потребуется что-то ещё? В этом столбце должно храниться значение CSS-свойства: вы на 100% уверены, что вам не потребуются другие форматы? Или можно ограничиться подмножеством CSS-значений, совместимых с другими ожидаемыми форматами? И доходя до экстрима: нельзя ли будет уменьшить объём летающих по сети данных, воспользовавшись CSS-классами в общих стилях?